# Table in parallel environment

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

If I have a table in `parallel =2` environment , does it mean I have 2 separate tables?

For example, I use a table for calculating the message (received from kafka) counts (and average values) for a window period (`select count (x),avg(x) from TABLE(TUMBLE()) ...` ) and use then  `toChangelogStream()`.  if I have 1M messages passed from kafka to this table in a window period, is the result  we have, 2 messages in 2 streams , each with count value 500K? If yes, is there a way to use the table in parallel =2 but get the total count?